# Detect Browser Support for display:inline-block

Tags: javascript, css, cross-browser, browser-detection

How can you detect if a browser supports the CSS attribute display:inline-block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to detect that with Javascript as it is a pure CSS attribute that does not relate to any object or function in Javascript.  The best thing I can tell you is to check [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html#inlineblock) for a pretty good compatibility list and use CSS to create a workaround.

Comment: @Alan H.: Hi! I don't know you, but I appreciate your constructive criticism on my answer! I also look forward to your answer to this question in which you show us how to do it. You are going to show us the way, right? :)

Comment: http://peter.michaux.ca/articles/feature-detection-state-of-the-art-browser-scripting Actually, Christopher Swasey offers a way to detect it with JS in his answer below. And at least Alan H. did write what he thought is the problem in your answer. I get downvotes to old answers without that luxury.

Comment: @Boldewyn: I would consider that the article you link to and Christopher Swasey's answer below to both be workarounds (*good* workarounds, but workarounds nonetheless). I still believe there is no "clean" way to detect browser support for a particular CSS feature. Also I would hardly call Alan's comment a luxury. :)

Answer (score 12):

Well, here's what you can go if you want to do it purely by examining the bavhiour of the browser w/ javascript instead of user agent sniffing:

Set up a test scenario, and a control scenario. With, say, the following structure:

- div

  - div w/ content "test"
  - div w/ content "test2"

Insert one copy into the document with the two internal divs set to inline-block, and insert another copy into the document with the two internal divs set to block. If the browser supports inline-block, then the containing divs will have different heights.

<strike>Alternate answer:</strike>

You can also use getComputedStyle to see how the browser is treating a given element's css. So, in theory, you could add an element with "display: inline-block," and then check the computedStyle to see if it survived. Only problem: IE doesn't support getComputedStyle. Instead, it has currentStyle. I don't know if currentStyle functions identically (presumably it functions similarly to the behaviour we want: disregarding "invalid" values).

Comment: I just tested this (via [@Alan H's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5049711/2688) [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JvTBZ/)) and `currentStyle` shows `inline-block` for elements where it's not supported (i.e. `div`s in IE 6 & 7)

Comment: Your other test does work (at least, in the clean room of jsFiddle): http://jsfiddle.net/bdukes/cHUps/5/

Answer (score 7):

According to the [QuirksMode charts](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html#t03), the only mainstream browsers not supporting `inline-block` are IE6 and 7. (Well, they support it, but only for elements which have a native `display` type of `inline`.) I'd just assume it is supported and then apply a workaround for IE6/7 via [conditional comments](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html).

(Note: I'm ignoring Firefox 2's lack of support for `inline-block` and assuming the vast majority of users have upgraded to FF3, but brief googling didn't unearth any numbers to back that up. YMMV.)

If determining support from JavaScript is your only option however, you'll have to fall back to user-agent sniffing. The [YAHOO.env.ua](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/docs/YAHOO.env.ua.html) class from the [YUI library](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/) is a handy chunk of code that you could copy and use. (It's BSD licensed, doesn't depend on other parts of the YUI library, and is only about 25-30 lines without comments)

Comment: Just checked the statistics on my website and they seem to support your assumption that most FF users have upgraded to FF 3. And IMO it's a good idea to design for the future anyway.

Answer (score 3):

By the way: There is [a neat way](http://blog.mozilla.com/webdev/2009/02/20/cross-browser-inline-block/) to implement cross-browser inline-blocks in IE6+, FF2+, Opera and WebKit with CSS alone. (Not valid CSS, but still only CSS.)

Answer (score 2):

[Christopher Swasey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601118/detect-browser-support-for-displayinline-block/601288#601288) is quite correct.

I have set up a jsFiddle demo of his technique at http://ajh.us/test-inline-block.

The code is essentially:

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.style.cssText = 'display:inline-block';

// need to do this or else document.defaultView doesn't know about it
$('body').append(div); 
// that was jQuery. It’s possible to do without, naturally

var results = false;

if (div.currentStyle) {
    results = (div.currentStyle['display'] === 'inline-block');
} else if (window.getComputedStyle) {
  results = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(div,null).getPropertyValue('display')=== 'inline-block';  
}

//clean up
$(div).remove();

alert('display: inline-block support: '+results);
```

Please note this exact same technique also works for detecting `display: run-in` support.

Comment: Using this technique, my IE 6 and 7 machines both say that they support `inline-block` on a `div`, when, in reality, they both display it as a `block` element.